# Understanding Java Syntax from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, syntax

I bought myself a copy of "Cracking the Coding Interview" hoping to swat up on my algorithmic skills. I'm fairly competent with JavaScript, but could not make sense of the following snippet from near the beginning of the book. It creates a dynamic array, but there are several things which I'd like some help with understanding.

1) Presumably this method would be part of a class?
2) What does `ArrayList<String>` do, and why does it appear 3 times?
3) Why does String have `[]` after it?

If anyone could give a breakdown of the parts of the syntax which differ drastically for JavaScript that would be great (mainly those mentioned above). It would also be very helpful indeed to have a translation into JavaScript.

```
public ArrayList<String> merge(String[] words, String[] more) {
    ArrayList<String> sentence = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String w : words) sentence.add(w);
    for (String w : more) sentence.add(w);
    return sentence;
}
```

Comment: How about you try running it and letting us know?

Comment: And no, we're not going to translate this to another language for you.  I'm not sure what you think that will accomplish, but it definitely won't be anything of learning.

Comment: I want to read the book away from a screen and also don't want to yak shave "hello world" in yet another language.

Comment: Translation would be very helpful to me. Can't I be the judge of that? I expect it to give me a lot of insight that will help with my goal.

Comment: I bet you that the translation will be even more helpful to you if you try it yourself.

Comment: Maybe you should learn the basics about the language before trying to "decode" the code?

Comment: I don't have enough basic Java knowledge to attempt a translation in the constraints of time and mental energy available. I also don't wish to learn Java at this time. Just a bit of friendly help from anyone who wants to help me with my algorithmic studies.

Comment: You don't have enough what?

Comment: What's with the downvotes guys? My questions seems reasonable to me. Is it that you guys love Java and would like others to respect it as a language rather than "steal it's secrets" without investing the energy to learn the basics?

Comment: Just my humble opinion, and I have not voted in any way on this question, but a blatant unwillingness to learn basics does not seem to be a very good place to start for coding of any kind. And your questions are reasonable, but it's what tutorials are for, not what SO is for.

Comment: I'm baffled by it myself. It's well know that translations are incredibly powerful in opening whole dimensions of understanding (Rosetta stone?). I'm currently working full time as junior web developer and I'm learning all sorts of new things already as well as having sore eyes most of the time. I want to relax with a book which is highly recommended but happens to use a language I can't easily "read." I have another book called "From mathematics to generic programming" with an appendix on C++ for people who aren't familiar. I'd like the same kind of help and generosity with Java.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The method is called `ArrayList<String>` because it returns an object of class `ArrayList` consisting of strings. In general Java arrays are of fixed length but an object of class `ArrayList` is dynamic meaning its length changes.

It is used again to define sentence as being an object from the `ArrayList` class and the `<string>` to denote it consists of strings.

You can see the method takes in as arguments two `String[]`s this is just a Java array of strings. (remember arrays in Java are static length)

`.add` is a method that can be used by an object of `ArrayList` to add elements.

Then it adds the words into sentence, then returns sentence.

In Python I would do this just like this:

```
import numpy as np    
words = some list
more = some list 
def merge(x, y):
     sentence = np.array([])
     for w in x:
           sentence = np.append(sentence, w)
     for w in y:
           sentence = np.append(sentence, w)
     return sentence
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll try the Python version soon.

Comment: Downvoting without giving a reason is very unhelpful for me - How am I to judge the quality of this answer (which I'm assuming is perfectly good) when someone anonymously claims to "know better" but doesn't explain the supposed flaws?